# JavaScript changing image when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover

I am trying to write a script, so that when someone hovers over an image, that same images changes to a different one, ie. I hover over up.png, and it changes to up_highlighted.png, when the mouse goes off the image it should change back.

However I can't seem to get it working despite all my attempts, here is the relevant code of what I have tried so far:

```
print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" class=\"thumbsbtn1\" style=\"position:absolute;top:60px;left:1px;width:28px;\" onhover=\"hover_up()\" onclick=\"increase_rating()\">";
```

```
function hover_up(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oldSrc = $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src');

    $('.thumbsbtn1').hover(function() {
        //on hover of your element

        $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src','/images/up_hover.png');
    }, function() {
        //when the cursor leaves your element

        $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src', oldSrc);
    });
});
}
```

PS. I do not wish to use sprites.

Comment: this questions has no relevance to my other question. I am using jquery for this.

Comment: Fair enough. On another note - and related to the discussion on the other question - your "doesn't work" responses below suggest that you expect answers to work perfectly without any subsequent debugging. That may happen sometimes, but usually it is the case that you need to take someone's helpful answer and tweak it for your situation. If it "doesn't work", find out why. Maybe a hover-over image is wrong, or it isn't triggering for some reason? Use temporary `alert` boxes to trace the flow of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old School: http://jsfiddle.net/PAGUp/

```
var elem = document.getElementById('targetImg');
var oldSrc;
elem.onmouseover = function() {
    oldSrc = elem.src;
    elem.src = 'http://www.eclipse-developers.com/images/up_hover.png';
}

elem.onmouseout = function() {
    if(typeof oldSrc !== 'undefined') {
        elem.src = oldSrc;
    }
}
```

I'm sure the jquery is more pithy. Essentially you need a variable to hold the 'old' src URL, and mouseover and mouseout handlers to set the new URL and back it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wrap `$(document).ready` inside hover_up function. Note that I have removed onhover from HTML

Try

```
print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" class=\"thumbsbtn1\" style=\"position:absolute;top:60px;left:1px;width:28px;\" onclick=\"increase_rating()\">";


$(document).ready(function() {
    var oldSrc;
    $(document).on('hover', '.thumbsbtn1', function () {
        oldSrc = $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src');
        $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src','/images/up_hover.png');
    }, function () {
        $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src', oldSrc);
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3332590 Try the updated code. I think you are creating the img element after the page is loaded. i.e, using JS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BZExF/ as you can see, doesnt work, also not that i have just changed the image path to external of course for that sake of jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you given up? ;/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
print "<img src=\"/images/up.png\" class=\"thumbsbtn1\" style=\"position:absolute;top:60px;left:1px;width:28px;\" onhover=\"hover_up(this)\" onclick=\"increase_rating()\" onmouseout=\"hover_out(this)\">";


var oldSrc;
function hover_up(e){
oldSrc = $('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src');
$('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src','/images/up_hover.png');
}  
function hover_out(e){
$('.thumbsbtn1').attr('src',oldSrc);
}
```